# Openejb XAResource

Tags: ejb, openejb

I'm trying to create an openejb initial context that would allow me to connect to a DB2 XA data source by using the following code:

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
//excluding everything not related
p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude", ".*");
p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.include", ".*my-application.*");
p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.filter.descriptors", "true");        
p.put("data-source", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
p.put("data-source.JdbcDriver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
p.put("data-source.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:db2://the-url");       
p.put("data-source.username", "username");
p.put("data-source.password", "pass");
```

The error that I get is :

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection does not have a registered XAResource jdbc:db2://the-url, UserName=username, IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture

I'm sure that the registered `XAResource` that I'm asked for should be `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource` - but how to supply this info? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using ibm JDK, there is a bug in the WeakHashmap, which can lead to exactly to this error.